# How to tell which version of ASP.NET a code is written in?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I inherited a code base from a different department. It’s written in ASP.NET and VB.NET. How to tell which version of ASP.NET it’s written in? My Visual Studio (on MacOS) could not open the project locally on my device:

[image: VS error message]

This might help: in the sln file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28307.271
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{XXXXXXXXX}") = "xxxx", "xxxx", "{xxxxxxx}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/xxxx"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "xxxx\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\xxxxxx\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/xxxxx"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "xxxxx\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\xxxxxxx\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "62416"
        SlnRelativePath = "xxxxxx\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {xxxxxxxxx}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxxx}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {xxxxxxxx}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 2
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {xxxxxxx}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = xxxxxxx
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccWebProject1 = true
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = xxxx
        SccProjectName1 = xxxxxxx
        SccLocalPath1 = xxxxxxx
        SccProjectEnlistmentChoice1 = 2
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess off the top of my head, as I don't have access to such a project right now, but you might open the project file in a text editor and see if there's anything relevant in there.

Comment: I added more details to the questions with screenshot of the vs error

Comment: `.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5` is the clue there. `4.5` is your answer.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I understand this is the version of .net framework. What about the version of asp.net. Is it asp.net webform or mvc? Etc.

Comment: I don't think you can know that from the .sln file. Is there a .vbproj file for the asp.net project specifically? To be honest though it's pretty easy to spot WebForms and MVC just by looking at the files and folders in the project. If you get files with .aspx and .aspx.vb extensions, then it's WebForms. If you don't have that but instead you have folders called "Views" and "Controllers", and the Views folder contains files with .vbhtml extensions, then it's MVC. The two types are structured so differently that you can usually tell the difference in a few seconds.

Comment: The `sln` file says nothing about the *project's* framework. A solution can have many projects. The only projects you can open in Visual Studio for Mac are Mono and .NET Core. You can't open .NET Framework projects

Comment: Open its project in an editor (.vbproj) and you should know the details. However, based on what you provided in comments, that's a .NET Framework project which you can only open/edit on Windows in Visual Studio, not on macOS with VS for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Look the code follows please.
`TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"`

It says that your code is using .Net Framework 4.5.